# How to build a simple mobile app based on a simple python program?

Tags: python, android, azure-mobile-services, mobile-application

I recently participated in the company's internal Hackathon, using Python and Azure's image processing API to make a simple program to scan products. The basic idea is to place a specific product in front of the camera and the program will redirect to the product page with more details.

Our product manager is quite interested in this project, asking if I can make a mobile app. I am a data engineer and has almost zero experience on the mobile side. Just wondering if there is an easy way to migrate / re-do the project I just described and make it preferably an app compatible with both Android and IOS. What tech stack do I need to learn to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can try it with https://kivy.org/#home - this should work with python.
If you do not want to stick to python, there are lots of frameworks, that might fit your needs:

- Flutter https://flutter.dev/
- Kotlin https://kotlin.org/
- Xamarin https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin
- React Native https://www.reactnative.com/

this list is growing fast...